# Raspberry : How install a usb to vga adapter?

Tags: raspbian, usb, display

I have the raspberry pi 3 Model B V1.2 and I connect my hdmi monitor on it. So now I buy a usb to vga adapter (USB2VGAE2 from Startech) and connect another monitor by this adapter. How can I install this usb to vga adapter on the raspberry. And make the raspberry identifies the second monitor and display the content.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You may need different hardware (DisplayLink chipset), but someone out there has done similar. 
 https://www.androidcentral.com/can-you-use-multiple-monitors-raspberry-pi-3-b

Answer (score 1):

You need a Linux driver for this device which you can either build yourself, or expect RPi developers to build for you (which happens when the driver is accepted in mainline kernel). Currently there's no such driver for the MCT Trigger 1+ chipset.

Exagear works by emulating x86 userland around an ARM kernel. It cannot insert an x86 kernel driver into an ARM kernel. Incidentally, installing drivers in Wine is not how you can use a Windows driver in Linux, you need something like NdisWrapper to do the trick. But, as I mentioned, the trick will not work on ARM. Also see [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=193649) related thread.

Look into USB 2.0 DisplayLink devices, specifically the ones based on DL-1XX chipset. AFAIK those have a mainline driver called `udl`. You should check if it works on the RPi before you buy though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are going to need to find a driver for this. The manufacturer has one for Windows but doesn't mention Linux - if you do find one I bet it would be for x86 and not arm hardware. I also believe the device uses the on-board GPU which would need to support an additional display. I maybe wrong but I don't think it's suitable for the RPI.

Comment: Yes, this adapter have a driver for Windows not for Linux. I install the ExaGear Desktop with Wine. ExaGear Emulate a architecture i686 when he launched. With Wine I install the driver of usb to vga adapter (USB2VGAE2 from Startech). But I don't have the icon adapter in the menu bar of raspbian os (http://content.etilize.com/user-manual/1013380423.pdf).

Comment: The link you posted recommends a CPU @ 1.5Ghz. Even when overclocked the PI runs in the Mhz. Trying to install Win software with layer upon layer of emulation is going to be fragile at best. Here's a [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/exagear-desktop-review-virtualisation-on-pi/) to an article from MagPi on ExaGear which concludes "In all, we found ExaGear Desktop provided no practical use for Windows software". I know it's probably not what you want to hear, but there are too many hurdles to make it work.

Comment: I figure you're pretty keen to get this working as you've asked three questions along the same theme. There are a few posts on-line about multi-monitors on the PI. None look easy and most complain about CPU performance. Personally I think it's more proof-of-concept than practical. However, if you're still determined displayLink devices seem to be something to look at, there's possibly a driver for linux - don't rush out and buy one. You're going to need to re-compile the kernel. Do some research and ask specific questions along the way. Good luck

Comment: I have also a kensington usb video adapter (https://www.kensington.com/ce/ca/6843/8589633974/usb-30-multidisplay-adapter) DisplayLink Certified. I will with it too. I must find a process to install the driver. I try to install the driver for windows with the Wine from ExaGear Desktop but the soft don't work don't identify le system (OS).

Comment: But I have a green screen on my second monitor. How config the Xorg.conf file for my DisplayLink USB Graphic Device ?

Comment: Hello, I found this web page : https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/ where he talks about how to install displaylink-debian.sh a script for DisplayLink Driver. But I try but the script don't work.

Comment: Hi It looks as though you're making progress. I'm not an expert when it comes to Linux drivers. It maybe a good idea to open a new question with lots of detail for what you've tried and remember to include details as to why it's not working. It could be an architecture issue.